# Navigate to welcome page after login page using React Router Dom v6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm a beginner learning React and using React v 17.0.2, react-router-dom v 6.0.2. I'm following a course made for react-router-dom v4. I'm not able to get page navigation working if I try to navigate from a successful login to append a welcome message to the url. In v4 this is achieved by a `{this.props.history.push("/welcome")` method. I'm not able to something equivalent in V6. Specifically, I would like to know how to handle the loginClicked method.

Based on the helpful guidance from Himanshu Singh, I tried the following:

```
import { computeHeadingLevel } from '@testing-library/react'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'



class TodoApp extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TodoApp">
                <Router>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" exact element={<LoginComponent />} />
                        <Route path="/enlite" element={<LoginComponent />} />
                        <Route path="/welcome" element={<WelcomeComponent />} />
                    </Routes>

                </Router>
                {/* <LoginComponent /> */}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

class WelcomeComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Welcome to Enlite</div>

    }
}

class LoginComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: 'testuser',
            password: '',
            hasLoginFailed: false,
            showSuccessMessage: false
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.loginClicked = this.loginClicked.bind(this)
}


    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState(
            {
                [event.target.name]
                    : event.target.value
            })
    }


**loginClicked() {
        
        if (this.state.username === 'testuser' &&
            this.state.password === 'dummy') {
              
            function HandlePageNav() {
                let navigate = useNavigate()
                 navigate('/welcome')
            }

            **HandlePageNav();**
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ showSuccessMessage: false })
            this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true })
        }

}**

 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.hasLoginFailed && <div>Invalid Credentials</div>}
                {this.state.showSuccessMessage && <div>Welcome to Enlite</div>}
                User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={this.loginClicked}>Login</button>
            </div>
        )

    }


}
export default TodoApp
```

This gives the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

Basically calling hooks in class components is not supported. I also tried to completely do away with the function like this:

```
  loginClicked() {
        
        if (this.state.username === 'testuser' &&
            this.state.password === 'dummy') {

                let navigate = useNavigate()
                 navigate('/welcome')
  
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ showSuccessMessage: false })
            this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true })
        }

}
```

This gives a compile error:

> Line 85:32:  React Hook "useNavigate" cannot be called in a class
> component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or
> a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks   Line 89:13:
> 'HandlePageNav' is not defined
> no-undef

The above makes me wonder if I need to refactor my entire code into a function component or if there's a way to achieve this page navigation but keeping the class component. Other than that I would appreciate any help or insights on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**UseNavigate Hook will not work here because hooks are meant to be used in `functional` components not `class` components**.

What you can do for now is, *since no proper doc is provided for class component*

- **Try to use `Functional` Components** : the most easiest way
- Use a `HOC` component around the class component and `pass history` and other necessary props to it through that component.

**Note**: Here I tried second approach. You can follow this: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-moon-30br5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Himanchu. I tried both approaches you suggested and updated my question with the details. Unfortunately neither approach solved the problem. Thanks for pointing out that I forgot to call the function. When I called it I got an 'Invalid Hook Call' error. When I tried to navigate without the function, I got a compile error. Just wondering if these approaches worked for you and if I'm missing anything. Please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @jay tai, I got the problem now and edited the solution.

Comment: Hi @Himanshu. Thanks for this. I marked up the answer and I think both approaches are good solutions. I think the first approach is quite restrictive and forces you to use functional components. I prefer to have and would expect React to have more flexibility around this issue, particularly when you're able to use Class components in the older but not newer versions. I prefer the second approach. Again, however, I don't understand why passing history has to involve so many workarounds when it was simply achievable in V4 with a single line.